# When editing my menu on wordpress wp-admin, page reloads everytime I click a menu item

Tags: wordpress

My site is currently running wordpress 5.1.1.

I have since realised that whenever I edit my menu on Apprearance > Menus, the page has to refresh every time I click to expand a menu item.

Does this happen to everyone? Is it a new update I missed? Or a plugin malfunction?

Help solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be the case of reloading. 
First see on hovering to menu item if the link is somewhat like this: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?edit-menu-item=165**#menu-item-settings-165** a # afterwards. if not then something is wrong. might be some conflict in jQuery you wrote of some plugins

Comment: It is exactly as that link you've sent except after the number on menu-item-settings there is %09%09%09%09%09%09

Comment: Can you please give that link or a screenshot will be helpful. 
Are you using any 3rd party plugins or custom code ?

Comment: Ahmed, thanks for trying to help. It was a minor bug on the main theme. I updated to the latest version and the problem got resolved. The theme is Martfury, for anyone else who might encounter the same problem.

Comment: Most Welcome, @ItsyBitsyFisty. Thanks for letting us know.